# Adding extra empty embedded form to collection within Symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony, associations, entity

In a controller, I create a collection of forms to edit multiple category entities at once:

```
private function createCategoriesCrudForm($categoryCollection)
{
  $new_category = new reportcategory();
  $new_category->setName('New category?');
  $categoryCollection->addCategory($new_category);

  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($categoryCollection)
  ->add('categories', 'collection', array
  (
    'required' => false,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'prototype' => true,
    'prototype_name' => 'proto_category',
    'type' => new reportCategoryType()
  ))->getForm();
  return $form;
}
```

As you can see, I create forms for each existing category and an empty one that might be used to add a new category.

Each category has a number of items. These items are loaded in the reportCategoryType() form, and they are also a collection of forms. They are added like this:

```
->add('items', 'collection', array
(
  'required' => false,
  'allow_add' => true,
  'prototype' => true,
  'prototype_name' => 'proto_item',
  'type' => new reportItemType()
))
```

This all works, but now I want to add an empty reportItemType() form to the items collection of each category. This also for the purpose of filling it in, and adding an extra item to the category.

Therefor my question is: 
How can I add an extra empty item to a collection in a form?

As you will notice, for the categories I create the collection myself where the items collection for each category is processed by Symfony2 based on the association (OneToMany) in its form definition.

I know there is a way of doing this using jQuery and prototypes, but I aim to avoid that.

**ADDED:**

One solution I thought of, is looping through each category, fetching its items, adding an empty item, and then adding each category to the categoryCollection. In code, this looks like this:

```
$cats = $this->getEm()->getRepository(....)->findAll();
$categoriesCollection = new reportCategoryCollection();
foreach ($cats as $cat)
{
  $new_item = new reportItem();
  $new_item->setName("New item?");
  $cat->addItem($new_item);
  foreach ($cat->getItems() as $item)
  $categoriesCollection->addCategory($cat);
}
```

But this leads to an error:

> FormException: Entities passed to the choice field must be managed.
>   Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

However, persisting them is not an option as I would be storing many new entities in the DB whether they have meaning or not. Basically, I would like to provide extra empty item *forms* to optionally be filled out. I don't want to add extra empty items...

Comment: In the same kind of situation I did like you did. When persisting, I was checking if one of the required property was `null` and if yes, was skipping the persist call for this entity.